# How can I determine where a file resides (full path), while having the knowledge of the partial path?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I am interested in the file `C:\Folder1\Folder2\Config\Hello.yaml`.

`\Folder1\Folder2\Config\Hello.yaml` is the same for everyone but everything behind the first `\` is different.

How can I find the full path and save it in a variable?

Comment: `Resolve-Path`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "**in front of** the first `\`"? Otherwise it makes no sense.

You have to search through all possible paths.

```
Get-ChildItem *\Folder1\Folder2\Config\Hello.yaml -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
```